What would be the ideal solution for this problem?
I want to create a CI/CD pipeline where

The developer pushes his code to the Github repo.
Github action runs the unit tests, and upon the passing of all the tests, it lets you merge the PR.
On K8s cluster an argocd deployment listens for changes on this repo. Upon a new merge, it triggers a build process. Here is my confusion: I want Kaniko to build a docker image from this repo and push this image to GCR where K8s is running.
Once the Kaniko build is successful, I want to update the helm chart image version to the latest tag and then deploy the actual application via argocd.

I am not sure how to transition from step 3 to step 4. I will be able to build and push the image to GCR, but how do I update the new image tag in the deployment spec of the application, and how do I trigger the deployment?
I am also not sure about the directory structure.
For now, I am thinking of putting the Kaniko spec here.
But then that means I'll have to create a new repo just for the specs of this application deployment. Does that make sense, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Building the image should happen in the CI. ArgoCD should not be involved yet. Maybe Argos Workflows could though.

@GaëlJ I believe CI ends when the code is merged into the main Git branch. Building and storing the Docker image should be part of the CD process. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Could you please change your title to be more specific?

@Nagri, it always depends on your needs/habits/requirements but most of the time it is the CI that builds an artifact, push it to a registry so that it's available for deployment. CD is somehow detecting there's a new artifact and deploying it. CD doesn't build artifacts.

Your question includes different topics which makes it hard to cover all of them here. I'll try to address most of them.
Argo CD, as the name represents itself, can only handle CD part.
Argo CD is a declarative, GitOps continuous delivery tool for Kubernetes.
Argo CD follows the GitOps pattern of using Git repositories as the source of truth for defining the desired application state.
since you are using GitHub, you need to define your pipeline, within GitHub workflow(action) + modification of your manifest files where your applications(k8s files) are located --> it means all the above steps(1 to 4) you mentioned.
for the build and push step, I believe you need an Actions Runner Controller (ARC) as a self-hosted runner, so you can trigger the runner you have to build and push your image.
# for e.g. in your Github workflow, you can use:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: 
        - self-hosted   # required label to tigger your runner.

in the official doc of Kaniko, I could only find an example for GitLab CI, but you can use it to get the idea for GitHub.[LINK]
So now let's assume that you have your GitHub workflow, which triggers based on the specific branch, within the pipeline, you are building and pushing your image, and now it's time to change K8s manifest, regarding the new image tag.
also, need to define IMAGE_TAG vars in your GitHub workflow.
    - name: Deploy to staging
      run: |
        sudo wget -qO /usr/local/bin/yq https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/yq_linux_amd64
        sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/yq
        sudo git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.GIT_CLONE_SECRET }}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
        sudo git clone https://<REPO_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_HELM_CHARTS>
        cd helm-charts    # this part, is related to your repo structure
        sudo yq -i eval '.image.tag = "${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}"' <YOUR_PATH_TO_HELM_VALUES>/values.yaml
        sudo git config user.email <YOUR_GIT_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE>
        sudo git config user.name <YOUR_GIT_USERNAME_HERE>
        sudo git add .
        sudo git commit -m "image updated with ${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}"
        sudo git push origin master  # CHANGE IT TO THE BRANCH YOUR K8S MANIFEST ARE.

and about your directory and deployment structure, the official ArgoCD doc can help you: LINK
